# .NET Core - RequireHttpsAttribute causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Ubuntu with Apache2

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-core, https

Using .NET Core 2.0 if I follow the official documentation to enforce HTTPS the website fails to load with the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new .NET Razor App:
   dotnet new razor -o aspnetcoreapp
2. Add the two snippits of code from documentation detailed here:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.0
3. Deploy to Apache2 running on Ubuntu 17.10 (not tested on older versions) where conf passes connection to Kestrel server using this code:

`ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/`

If code from step 2 is removed then the website works fine over HTTP or HTTPS (but obviously does not redirect) but if this code is added the site fails to load with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS over either HTTP or HTTPS.
It seems the methods have changed with .NET Core 2.1 but this has not yet been released.

Answer (score 9):

You've set your passthrough as `http`, rather than `https`. Apache here is running as a reverse proxy, so it simply forwards the request on to your passthrough server(s), which it will always do over `http`, based on your config here. Then, since the ASP.NET Core app is configured to require HTTPS, it redirects, causing a new request to hit Apache, which it then forwards *again* over `http`.

Long and short, you need to passthrough to `https`, not `http`. Alternatively, you can remove the HTTPS-only requirement from your ASP.NET Core app, and instead enforce HTTPS in Apache.

Comment: This answer was pretty helpful at solving [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60286204/335858), which has been driving me nuts for almost two weeks. I still don't understand why my issue has been manifesting itself only in a limited scenario (namely, mobile-over-cellular) but the solution to HTTPS on IIS, rather than on ASP.NET Core, has worked like a charm. By the way, if you have an explanation of what was going on in my mobile-over-cellular scenario, you are welcome to post an answer at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic, there should be a place to cause a circular redirection.If you use a reverse proxy, check if the HttpContext is correctly getting the Https status